# How to select Distinct names from a xml database using LINQ?

Tags: c#, sql, xml, linq, windows-phone-7

i am trying this query to get all the city's

```
var queryAllCustomers = from cust in loadedCustomData.Descendants("record")
                                select (string)cust.Element("City") ;
```

so it returns all city's including repeated, but i only want to get distinct city i.e to repeat only ones so how to achieve that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [Distinct Extension Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
var queryAllCustomers = (from cust in loadedCustomData.Descendants("record")
                            select (string)cust.Element("City")).Distinct();
```

Comment: Can't get more obvious than that, eh?